# ExtJS 4 RadioGroup Change Event Fires Twice

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm using ExtJS 4.0.7, am new to Ext, and am using the new MVC architecture. I have a RadioGroup that, upon change, I want to use to reveal more UI elements. The problem is, that the change event fires twice for the RadioGroup. I'm assuming this is because both Radios fire an event for having their values change.

Is there a way to listen for a change to either the RadioGroup or Radios with the same name that will fire only once? In my experience with jQuery and Flex, I would expect a RadioGroup to only fire once.

Here's the RadioGroup code in my view:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    id: 'WheatChoice',
    padding: '',
    layout: {
        padding: '-3 0 4 0',
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    fieldLabel: 'Choose Model',
    labelPad: 5,
    labelWidth: 80,
    allowBlank: false,
    columns: 1,
    flex: 1,
    anchor: '60%',
    items: [
        { xtype: 'radiofield', id: 'SpringWheat', padding: '2 10 0 0', fieldLabel: '', 
          boxLabel: 'Spring', name: 'wheat-selection', inputValue: '0', flex: 1 },
        { xtype: 'radiofield', id: 'WinterWheat', padding: '2 0 0 0', fieldLabel: '',
          boxLabel: 'Winter', name: 'wheat-selection', inputValue: '1', checked: true, flex: 1 }
     ]
}]
```

Here's the relevant code in my Controller:

```
init: function() {
     this.control({
         '#WheatChoice': {
            change: this.onWheatChange
         }
     });
},

onWheatChange: function(field, newVal, oldVal) {
    //this fires twice
    console.log('wheat change');
}
```

Comment: Confirmed ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/4sTQQ/)). Looks like a bug.

Comment: this is not a work around. I've only created showcase of the bug.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the stuff I posted. This is a workaround: Change the selector to '#WheatChoice radio' and use logic in the event listener to ignore any new values not equal to true.

Comment: i have found that radiogroups and checkboxgroups are essentially unusable in the 4.x betas...best wait for the RTM release

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132176-radiogroup-change-event-fired-twice/page2

evant says this will be fixed with 4.1, so it's definitely a bug.

However, you can deal with the situation pretty easily:

```
//borrowing your function
onWheatChange: function(rg, sel) {
    var selection = sel['wheat-selection'];

    if (!(selection instanceof Object)) {
        alert(selection);
    }

}
```

var selection will be the new value. I know it doesn't solve the two event firing problem, but hopefully this helps!

Comment: I'm accepting this, because it is a bug and workaround works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it fires twice is because your radio group has two changes happening.

A radio button is changing from `checked=true` to `checked=false` and then your newly clicked radio button is changing from `checked=false` to `checked=true`. This should really be an expected thing.

What if you wanted to do something when a radio button was no longer checked? You'd miss that entire event. Really you should just be doing a check on your listener function to only listen for the radio button that has `checked=true`.

Comment: This is a solution I've also employed, but I don't agree with wanting to know about both a Radio buttons in a group. A RadioGroup should, in theory, provide one value and one event.

Answer (score 0):

It might be getting fired because the initial value is being set and that triggers the event. Try adding a third radio element and see if it fires three times.

Comment: I did it with a different radio group with four items. It fires twice. Once to tell me the newly selected radio value changed and once to tell me that the old radio value changed to checked=false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
change : function(thisFormField, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
          if (!Ext.isArray(newValue.myTransitionsRadio)) {
                 // Code goes here.
          }
```

Here myTransitionsRadio in my case, is the common name given to all radio buttons.

Thanks
Nagendra